# Connecting to openfire server using smack api

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

I've been trying to connect to my local openfire server using smack api. But i'm unable to connect.

```
 Exception in thread "Smack Packet Reader (0)" java.lang.AssertionError
11:08:23 AM SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='localhost' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' from='admin@localhost' xml:lang='en'>
11:08:23 AM RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="my-openfire-domain" id="1qpatj8yxs" xml:lang="en" version="1.0"> at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:992)

    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:937)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.

    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:106)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:85)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkForResponse(SynchronizationPoint.java:253)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWait(SynchronizationPoint.java:146)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWaitOrThrow(SynchronizationPoint.java:125)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:837)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:360)
    at de.daarwin.charls.common.connect.ConnectionManager.login(ConnectionManager.java:25)
    at smack.ConnectionTest.testConnectionToLocalhost(ConnectionTest.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

There is code i use for connecting.

```
AbstractXMPPConnection connection;
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
        .setUsernameAndPassword(userName, password)
        .setServiceName("localhost")
        .setHost("localhost")
        .setPort(5222)
        .setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled) // Do not disable TLS except for test purposes!
        .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
        .build();

    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
    connection.connect().login();
```

I'm using Smack api 4.15 - But when using 4.3 I was still unable to connect.

What I'm trying to achieve - I want to build some kind of wrapper to openfire server, but it's pretty hard if I'm unable to connect.

The server is running on Java 1.8, and I'm pretty sure that's fine - I'm able to connect to it using a communicator like Spark.

Comment: if your problem solved, please vote my answer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using smack v4.3 but I saw some new bugs on it, and downgraded it to 4.2.2 and all functions works fine.
You can try to connect using `IP address` instead of `localhost`, but I recommend to use v4.2.2.

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
config.setHost("192.168.1.50");
config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
config.setSendPresence(false);
config.setHostAddress(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.50");
config.setPort(5222);
config.setResource("myResource");
config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
config.setXmppDomain("myDomain");
connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
connection.setUseStreamManagement(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i've figure it out:

```
 XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
    configBuilder.setHost(host);
    configBuilder.setServiceName(serviceName);
    configBuilder.setResource(resource);
    configBuilder.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
```

That's work for me.